# jibberish returned when using CURLOPT_URL

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to grab a pages data using CURLOPT_URL, to do so ive used the below code, which is working fine for other pages (with the exception of where the page uses relative paths to its css / js in which case those dont load) .

```
function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}               

echo grab_page("$page_to_get");
```

But when i load the page i get returned a screen of jibberish like this, but a whole page, same when i view the source.

---

[image]

---

Looking at the source of the page, through my browser, they seem to be using `charset=utf-8"`, im not sure if that has anything to do with it though ? Any ideas ?

Comment: try adding `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

Comment: Thanks, @Orangepill, that did it, if you want to put that as an answer ill mark it as accepted

Comment: just a note, reading though the docs, it seems by setting the encoding to blank - ie. curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "" - it will send a header containing all supported encoding types

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40000000+seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

will fix it if the encoding is know to be gzipped or as you stated

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
```

should tickle curl into negotiating the encoding itself (why this is not the default is beyond me)

Comment: I guess that's because cURL deals with more than just the HTTP(S) protocols, and that option wouldn't make sense.

Comment: but negotiating the encoding is part of the protocol itself ... I shouldn't have to opt in to have it do what is in the protocol spec.